# JQuery selector Multiple Parameters

Tags: jquery, selector

```
$('.field[id^=stat_]')

$('.field[value!=""]')
```

Is it possible to combine these into a single line?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is possible:

```
$('.field[id^=stat_][value!=""]')
```

See also: [jquery.com - Multiple Attribute Selector](http://api.jquery.com/multiple-attribute-selector/)
Working example: http://jsbin.com/ugafam/1/

Answer (score 4):

You could try: `$('.field[id^=stat_][value!=""]')`

Answer (score 3):

Sure!

```
$('.field[id^=stat_][value!=""]');
```

Answer (score 3):

try it like this this will get your work done

```
$('.field[id^=stat_][value!=""]');
```